# Error, self use in method call "getGpa" before all stored poperties are initialized

Tags: swift, self

```
class Classroom{
   var nameOfClass : String
   var students : [String]
   var grades : [Int]
   var gpa : Double
   var highestGrade : Int
 
 
   init(nameOfClass : String, students : [String], grades : [Int]){
       self.nameOfClass = nameOfClass
       self.students = students
       self.grades = grades
       self.gpa = self.getGpa()
       self.highestGrade = self.getHighestGrade()
   }
 
   func getGpa() -> Double{
       var sum : Int = 0
 
       for grade in grades{
           sum += grade
       }
 
       var length : Double = Double(grades.count)
       var avg : Double = Double(sum) / length
       return avg
   }
 
   func getHighestGrade() -> Int{
       var max : Int = grades[0]
 
       for grade in grades{
           if grade > max{
               max = grade
           }
       }
 
       return max
   }
 
}
```

How would I be able to successfully declare gpa to getGpa() and highestGrade to getHighestGrade()? I keep running into the self used in method call error. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Give initial values to gpa and highestGrade: var gpa : Double = 0.0; var highestGrade : Int = 0.
Also, add init() before self.gpa = self.getGpa()

Answer (score 0):

Declare gpa and highestGrade like this

```
var gpa: Double!
var highestGrade: Int!
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I am new to Apple Swift as I am more used to coding in java. I was wondering what the exclamation point does in this case?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to calculate the values in the `init` method with one-liners

```
class Classroom {
   var nameOfClass : String
   var students : [String]
   var grades : [Int]
   var gpa : Double
   var highestGrade : Int
 
   init(nameOfClass : String, students : [String], grades : [Int]){
       self.nameOfClass = nameOfClass
       self.students = students
       self.grades = grades
       self.gpa = Double(grades.reduce(0, +)) / Double(grades.count)
       self.highestGrade = grades.max() ?? 0
   }
}
```

Do you really need a `class`? And are all `var` really supposed to be mutated?

Comment: Thank you for the help! And the class was premade by our instructor as he told us to complete the code on the inside.

Comment: In Swift it's highly recommended to start always with a struct, a value type. Use a class only if you explicitly need a reference type.